# Error initializing cordova: Extension device not found in PhoneGap 2.9.0 and blackberry10 webworks application

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I have created a blackberry10 Application using webworks sdk. I am using phonwgap2.9.0 in that. Whenever I open my app , I get this javascript alert

[Error] Error initializing cordova: Extension device not found

What Should I do to avoid this alert coming up?

Comment: Let me try and understand, are you using phonegap, cordova, or webworks. As of Cordova 2.9, the BlackBerry10 implementation is no longer dependant on WebWorks.

Comment: using cordova @jeffheifetz

Comment: How did you get the distribution, from the cordova website or from source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This started happening again for me in Cordova 3.1.0 and 3.2.0 on Windows 7. Under Phonegap 3.0.0 we were able to get Device and many other plugins to install and run successfully. So in a worst case you could try 3.0.0 but I will post a better answer if I can patch up 3.2.0 to work again.