# Worklight 6.1 - Error on Blackberry 10

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10, cordova-3

I'm using Worklight Studio 6.1.0.00-20131219-1900 and trying to build an app for Blackberry 10
I create a new Worklight app (no customizations other than adding the blackberry 10 environment), run it on the Worklight server, and use ripple to build and deploy to the blackberry 10 simulator.

The app installs on the simulator, But when it launches, I immediately get a JavaScript error:

```
[ERROR] Error initializing Cordova: Extension Device not found
```

This is possibly related to a problem seen with Cordova 3.1  (see: [Error initializing cordova: Extension device not found in PhoneGap 2.9.0 and blackberry10 webworks application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270428/error-initializing-cordova-extension-device-not-found-in-phonegap-2-9-0-and-bla)) but I'm not seeing any solutions.

Is there any way to get Worklight 6.1 apps to work on Blackberry 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your issue is mentioned in infocenter

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.dev.doc%2Fdevref%2Ft_creating_a_new_ibm_BlackBerry_10_environment.html

basically, did you do the "ant qnx copy-extensions" command ?

Comment: ant qnx copy-extensions was what I was missing.  Thanks.